# Pyro - How to use HMac key with Name Server? CommunicationError: hmac key config not symmetric

Tags: python, pyro

I'm using Pyro 4.34, Python 2.7 and Jython 2.7.

**NameServer**. I can start the name server like this fine:

```
pyro4-ns --key abc
```

**Pyro Server**. The documentation states that I can set the `_pyroHmacKey` attribute on the Pyro daemon, but the `locateNS` method failed with a `NamingError cannot find Name Server`.

Looking at the API for `locateNS`, I see that it has an arg called `hmac_key`. If I get rid of the _pryoHmacKey and use that arg instead, the Pyro Server can start fine.

```
name_server = Pyro4.locateNS(hmac_key='abc')
```

**Client**. The documentation states that I can set the `_pyroHmacKey` attribute on the `proxy`:

```
proxy = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:test")
proxy._pyroHmacKey = 'abc'
```

However, the first call to a method on `proxy` fails with:

```
CommunicationError: cannot connect: hmac key config not symmetric
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pyro Server code, I removed the `_pyroHmacKey` attribtue from the Pyro daemon because I assumed that it only needed to be specified in the parameter to `Pyro4.locateNS()`. Once I added it back in, everything worked.

It looks like the hmac key needs to occur in both locations for everything to work.

```
name_server = Pyro4.locateNS(hmac_key='abc')
daemon = Pyro4.daemon()
daemon._pyroHmacKey = 'abc'
uri = daemon.register(Foo())
ns.register('test, uri)
daemon.requestLoop()
```